# How do I make a loop of 64 if statements to fill out each of the individual squares if pressing on it

Tags: java, loops, math

What I want the program to do is when I am pressing on any square it runs the setColor function for that particular square

[The image of the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHeYw.png)

Here is the code

```
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

    mX = e.getX();
    mY = e.getY();

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].length; j++) {

            if (mX >= x + 75 && mX <= x && mY >= y + 75 && mY <= y) {

                grid[i][j].setColor(r, g, b);

                x += 75;

            }
            x = 0;
            y += 75;
        }
    }
    repaint();
}
```

The grid is 8 by 8 meaning there are 64 squares. I am kind of stuck on this one and would appreciate some help :)

Comment: You shouldn't loop over all of the squares when the user clicks the button. Instead you should just set the color of the button that was clicked.

Comment: I'm assuming your grid is an extension JPanel or some other component.  Instead of having a monolithic mouselistener, add a listener to each grid item so it only has to manage itself.

Comment: I suggest you create buttons at each grid position (if you aren't already) and use  the higher level `ActionListener` and `actionPerformed()` with each button rather than `MouseListener` and `mousePressed()`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] for the full context of this code.

Comment: This can never be true:`if (mX >= x + 75 && mX <= x && mY >= y + 75 && mY <= y)`. Something (mX) can never by greater or equal than something + 75 and yet also be smaller than or equal to that same something. `if (mX <= x + 75 && mX >= x && mY <= y + 75 && mY >= y) {`. If you reverse the greater-than and smaller-than characters, it makes much more sense and the expression can then actually evaluate to `true` in some circumstances.

Comment: What is the point of this nested loop? Why don't you just divide `mX` and `mY` by 75 and round down to get the values of `i` and `j` corresponding to the clicked button. (Also, as @ErwinBolwidt said, `mX >= x + 75 && mX <= x` will never be true.)

Comment: Shouldn't the event have the object which is the source of the Event?

Comment: @r3mainer can you please give me an example of what you mean if you can, thanks